# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testMethod (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: android, junit

I tried to test my Activity, but I ran into the problem: when I try to run Android JUnit project it fails on start with this stack trace:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: test (java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:100)
at com.sogemobile.saytv.api.UploadAvatarTest2.<init>(UploadAvatarTest2.java:16)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:118)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:148)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:56)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:80)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:444)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:425)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:370)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4382)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

My test code is:

```
 public class UploadAvatarTest2 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<EmptyActivity_> {

    public UploadAvatarTest2() {
         super(EmptyActivity_.class);
         getActivity();
    }

    public void test(){
    }

 }
```

I've found that the problem is "getActivity()" call. If I place breakpoint at "super(EmptyActivity_.class)" debugger won't even stop on that. But if I remove "getActivity()" string debugger will stop. It looks fantastic, but it's true :) I tried to restart eclipse/emulator but it doesn't affect anything.

What should I do to solve the problem? :(

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call the getActivity() method in the constructor. Use it in the setUp method, overridden.

```
@Override

public void setUp(){
super.setUp();
currentActivity=getActivity();
...
...
}
```

proceed further.

Declare `currentActivity` in the class as a private object of `EmptyActivity_`